# ERROR: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tabla' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, net

Con este modelo de datos puedo insertar en la db sin problemas un registro:

Datos que ingresan del cliente:

```
{
 "userId": 10,
 "name": "Alimento 1",
 "description":"Descripcion 1",
 "units": "kilos",
 "price": 960.60,
 "images": "Imagen 1"
}
```

Modelo generado por entity framework:

```
public partial class Producto
    {
        public int IdProducto { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string? Unidades { get; set; }
        public decimal Precio { get; set; }
        public string? Foto { get; set; }
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }

        public virtual Usuario IdUsuarioNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Y esta es mi insercion con linq:

```
public Producto InsertProduct(InsertProductModel model, MQMContext db)
        {
            var user = db.Usuarios.Where(el => el.IdUsuario == model.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

            Producto newProduct = new Producto(); //para mandar nuevo producto a la db

            if (user == null)
                return newProduct;

            newProduct.IdUsuario = model.UserId;
            newProduct.Nombre = model.Name;
            newProduct.Descripcion = model.Description;
            newProduct.Precio = model.Price;
            newProduct.Unidades = model.Units;

            db.Productos.AddRange(newProduct);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return newProduct;
        }
```

Ahora cuando los datos desde el cliente son estos:

```
{
 "userId": 10,
 "name": ["Alimento 1","Alimento 2"]
 "description":["Descripcion 1","Descripcion 2"],
 "units": ["kilos","Kilos"],
 "price": [960.60,740],
 "images": ["Imagen 1", "Imagen 2"]
}
```

Con este modelo para recibir los datos:

```
public record InsertProductModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public List<string>? Name { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Description { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Units { get; set; }
    public List<decimal>? Price { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Images { get; set; }

}
```

Y esta insercion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.Name.Count; i++)
            {
                newProduct.IdUsuario = model.UserId;
                newProduct.Nombre = model.Name[i];
                newProduct.Descripcion = model.Description[i];
                newProduct.Precio = model.Price[i];
                newProduct.Unidades = model.Units[i];

                db.Productos.AddRange(newProduct);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Obtengo el error del titulo de este post. No se porque me tira ese error ya que no estoy queriendo actualizar el IdProducto (que es autoincrementable).

Hay alguna manera de crear un modelo de datos para ingresar registros a la db que no sea usando los que da entity por defecto? la idea seria sacar el idProducto (para que no de error, si es que eso lo causa) y tambien quisiera sacar el campo fotos, ya que eso lo necesito actualizar posteriormente con el IdProducto que me entrega la insercion.
Soy nuevo con c#/net Core y estoy bastante perdido con estos errores

Comment: Dentro del for, tienes que crear la nueva instancia de newProduct si la creas afuera, solo le estas cambiando los valores en la segunda iteracion, cuando le haces add, este ya tiene su id del identity

Comment: @StialManstike era ese el problema, muchisimas gracias!!